# Using Fullpage.js with Angular2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, fullpage.js

I'm trying to use fullpage.js with Angular2 project. So, inside my **index.html**, I have following:

```
<html>
   <head>
       ....
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/jquery.fullPage.css" />
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
       <script>
           $(document).ready(function() {
               $('#fullpage').fullpage();
           });
       </script>
   </head>
   <body>
         <div class="container" id="fullpage">
               <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
         </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Since this is Angular2 project, I have routed a few pages and each page contains a few number of sections. For example, in **home.html**:

```
<section id="home_section1" class="section">
    some text
</section>
<section id="home_section2" class="section">
    some text
</section>
```

However, the fullpage does not work. I cannot scroll at all. :( It only works if I put the sections tag inside index.html which means:

```
<html>
       <head>
           ....
           <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/jquery.fullPage.css" />
           <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
           <script>
               $(document).ready(function() {
                   $('#fullpage').fullpage();
               });
           </script>
       </head>
       <body>
             <div class="container" id="fullpage">
                   <section id="home_section1" class="section">
                       some text
                   </section>
                   <section id="home_section2" class="section">
                       some text
                   </section>
             </div>
       </body>
 </html>
```

Can anyone please help me? :(

Comment: Have you taken a look at the angular directives list in [the resources section of the fullpage.js documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#resources) ?

Comment: you have to initialize fullpage from within the component's ngOnInit method.   `ngOnInit(): void {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage();
  }`